# how to call an instance of another JPanel in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, mouseclick-event

i have a jscrollpane inserted in the CENTER of borderlayout of JFrame 
i have a JPANEL named "UI" already inserted into jscrollpane 
i want to insert a new JPanel name "OUTPUTPAGE1" into the jscrollpane  when a button is clicked in UI Jpanel

```
class OutputPage1 extends JPanel 
{
//JButton jb;
XDash xd;
Plain p;
YourPersonal yp;
    Heading sp; 
StartTalkTable sTalk;
AtGlance g;
BlueIndex in;
    JLabel image1,image2,image3,image4,image5;
    MemberInfo mi;
    OrangeBorder o1;
    Footer f;
OutputPage1()
{

    //jb=new JButton("HI");
    xd=new XDash();
    p=new Plain();
    yp=new YourPersonal();
    sp=new Heading("Statement Period: Jan 1, 2013 to Mar 31, 2013","#000000","#C7D9F1",13);           //Heading(String t,String fg,String bg,int size)//
            sp.setHorizontalAlignment(sp.CENTER);
            sp.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI",Font.BOLD,13));
    sTalk=new StartTalkTable();
    g=new AtGlance();
    in=new BlueIndex();
            image1=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/Syntel_Java/images/firstimage.jpg"));
    image2=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/Syntel_Java/images/secondimage.jpg"));
            image3=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/Syntel_Java/images/thirdimage.jpg"));
            image4=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/Syntel_Java/images/fourthimage.jpg"));
            image5=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/Syntel_Java/images/secondimage.jpg"));
            mi=new MemberInfo();
            o1=new OrangeBorder();
            f=new Footer();

    this.setLayout(null);


    //this.add(jb);
    //jb.setBounds(50,800,100,100);         //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

    this.add(xd);
            xd.setBounds(50,33,150,150);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(p);
            p.setBounds(100,36,150,150);            //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(yp);
            yp.setBounds(50,80,400,90);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

    this.add(sp);
    sp.setBounds(420,120,335,27);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

    this.add(sTalk);
    sTalk.setBounds(230,160,457,314);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

    this.add(g);
    g.setBounds(230,481,457,36);            //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

    this.add(in);
    in.setBounds(230,525,458,429);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(image1);
            image1.setBounds(50,187,138,138);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(image2);
            image2.setBounds(50,320,138,138);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(image3);
            image3.setBounds(50,453,138,138);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(image4);
            image4.setBounds(50,580,138,138);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(image5);
            image5.setBounds(50,700,138,138);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(mi);
            mi.setBounds(50,840,168,116);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(f);
            f.setBounds(220,1000,270,100);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

            this.add(o1);
            o1.setBounds(20,980,700,200);           //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//



    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(),1500));          //Dimension(int width, int height) //
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.decode("#C1FC79"),20));
}
 }






    class UI extends JPanel implements ActionListener,MouseListener
     {
    JButton account,member_details,loadTemplate,viewSummary;
    JLabel member_xplain1,member_xplain2;
    JTextField userID,memberID,firstName,lastName;
    JPasswordField password;
    Image bg1,bg2;
    JComboBox fdate,fmonth,fyear,tdate,tmonth,tyear;
    static int CURRENT=1;
    String[] dates,months,years;
UI()
    {
        account=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/account.jpg"));
        member_details=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/member.jpg"));
        loadTemplate=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/load_normal.jpg"));
        viewSummary=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/view_normal.jpg"));
        member_xplain1=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/member_xplain.jpg"));
        member_xplain2=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/member_details.jpg"));
        memberID=new JPasswordField(10);
        firstName=new JTextField("ENTER YOUR NAME",10);
        lastName=new JTextField("ENTER YOUR SURNAME",10);
        userID=new JTextField("Enter your UserID",10);
        password=new JPasswordField(10);
        dates=new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
        months=new String[]{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        years=new String[]{"2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"};
        fdate=new JComboBox(dates);
        fmonth=new JComboBox(months);
        fyear=new JComboBox(years);
        tdate=new JComboBox(dates);
        tmonth=new JComboBox(months);
        tyear=new JComboBox(years);


        this.setLayout(null);

        this.add(account);
        account.setBounds(352,582,266,45);         //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(member_details);
        member_details.setBounds(618,582,266,45);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(userID);
        userID.setBounds(610,160,160,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(password);
        password.setBounds(610,216,160,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(memberID);
        memberID.setBounds(610,160,160,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(firstName);
        firstName.setBounds(610,216,160,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(lastName);
        lastName.setBounds(610,272,160,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(fdate);
        fdate.setBounds(605,327,51,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(fmonth);
        fmonth.setBounds(656,327,100,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(fyear);
        fyear.setBounds(756,327,65,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(tdate);
        tdate.setBounds(605,382,51,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(tmonth);
        tmonth.setBounds(656,382,100,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(tyear);
        tyear.setBounds(756,382,65,28);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(loadTemplate);
        loadTemplate.setBounds(424,425,420,58);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//
        loadTemplate.setBorderPainted(false);

        this.add(viewSummary);
        viewSummary.setBounds(425,495,420,58);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//
        viewSummary.setBorderPainted(false);

         this.add(member_xplain1);
        member_xplain1.setBounds(350,96,551,485);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//

        this.add(member_xplain2);
        member_xplain2.setBounds(350,96,551,485);          //setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)//



        //ACTION LISTENER//
        viewSummary.addActionListener(this);
        loadTemplate.addActionListener(this);
        account.addActionListener(this);
        member_details.addActionListener(this);


        //MOUSE LISTENER//
        viewSummary.addMouseListener(this);
        loadTemplate.addMouseListener(this);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)              //public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)//
    {
        if(e.getSource()==account)
        {
            if(CURRENT==1)
            {
               //DO NOTHING//
            }
            if(CURRENT==2)
            {
                CURRENT=1;
                this.repaint();
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource()==member_details)
        {
            if(CURRENT==1)
            {
                CURRENT=2;
                this.repaint();
            }
            if(CURRENT==2)
            {
                //DO NOTHING//
            }
        }
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==loadTemplate)
        {
            loadTemplate.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/load_hover.jpg"));
        }
        if(e.getSource()==viewSummary)
        {
            viewSummary.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/view_over.jpg"));
        }
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==loadTemplate)
        {
            loadTemplate.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/load_normal.jpg"));
        }
        if(e.getSource()==viewSummary)
        {
            viewSummary.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/view_normal.jpg"));
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(CURRENT==1)
        {
            bg1=new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/1.jpg").getImage();
            g.drawImage(bg1,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);


             //SETTING PAGE2 ELEMENTS TO FALSE//
                memberID.setVisible(false);
                firstName.setVisible(false);
                lastName.setVisible(false);
                fdate.setVisible(false);
                fmonth.setVisible(false);
                fyear.setVisible(false);
                tdate.setVisible(false);
                tmonth.setVisible(false);
                tyear.setVisible(false);
                loadTemplate.setVisible(false);
                viewSummary.setVisible(false);
                member_xplain2.setVisible(false);


                //SETTING PAGE1 ELEMENTS TO TRUE//
                userID.setVisible(true);
                password.setVisible(true);
                member_xplain1.setVisible(true);
        }
        if(CURRENT==2)
        {
            member_xplain1.setVisible(false);
            userID.setVisible(false);
            password.setVisible(false);
            bg1=new ImageIcon("D:/SYNTEL_JAVA_PROJECT/images/2.jpg").getImage();
            g.drawImage(bg1,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);


             //SETTING PAGE2 ELEMENTS TO TRUE//
                memberID.setVisible(true);
                firstName.setVisible(true);
                lastName.setVisible(true);
                fdate.setVisible(true);
                fmonth.setVisible(true);
                fyear.setVisible(true);
                tdate.setVisible(true);
                tmonth.setVisible(true);
                tyear.setVisible(true);
                loadTemplate.setVisible(true);
                viewSummary.setVisible(true);


                //SETTING PAGE1 ELEMENTS TO FALSE//
                userID.setVisible(false);
                password.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}








     class Demo extends JFrame implements AdjustmentListener,MouseListener
      {
      Demo x;
      UI ui;
      OutputPage1 op1;
      JScrollPane jsp,jsp2;
      Demo()
      {
          ui=new UI();
          op1=new OutputPage1();
          jsp=new JScrollPane(ui,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
          jsp.setViewportView(ui);

          this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


          this.add(new BlackPanel(),BorderLayout.WEST);
          this.add(new BlackPanel(),BorderLayout.EAST);
          this.add(new BlackPanel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
          this.add(new BlackPanel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          this.add(jsp,BorderLayout.CENTER);

          ui.loadTemplate.addMouseListener(this);
          jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
          jsp.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
          this.setVisible(true);
          this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
          x=this;
      }


      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
          if(e.getSource()==ui.loadTemplate)
          {

                jsp.setViewportView(op1);
                jsp.setVisible(false);
                op1.setVisible(true);
                jsp.getViewport().revalidate();

             // new Demo();
              //jsp.getViewport().repaint();

          }
      }
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
      {}
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
      {}
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
      {}
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
      {}


      //ADJUSTMENT LISTENER//
      public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)           //adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) //
      {
          jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setEnabled(true);
          jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement(10);
          jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
      }
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
          Demo z=new Demo();
      }
}
```

I GOT THE SOLUTION BY WRITING A MUCH MORE SIMPLER CODE WHICH PERFORMED THE TASK WHICH I WANTED DO WITH THE COMPLEX ONE....hope it helps all who have the same trouble :) :)
 `

```
      class Panel1 extends JPanel
      {
      JLabel jb1;
      JButton but;
      Panel1()
      {
        jb1=new JLabel("I AM ON PANEL 1");
        but=new JButton("click me to go to PANEL2");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(jb1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(but,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     }
   }
        class Panel2 extends JPanel
        {
           JLabel jb2;
           Panel2()
           {
             jb2=new JLabel("NOW PANEL 2 SHOULD APPEAR");

             this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            this.add(jb2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
           }
    }
  class Trial extends JFrame implements MouseListener
 {
   JFrame mainFrame;
   Panel1 p1;
 Panel2 p2;
 JScrollPane jsp;
Trial()
{
    p1=new Panel1();
    p2=new Panel2();
    jsp=new JScrollPane(p1);


    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    p1.but.addMouseListener(this);


    this.add(jsp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{}
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
   {}
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {}
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    if(e.getSource()==p1.but)
    {
        jsp.setViewportView(p2);
        jsp.getViewport().revalidate();
        System.out.println("YES I AM LISTENING TO YOU");
    }
   }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new Trial();
  }
}`
```

and it does the trick.

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: the code is pretty damaged one to be honest but here you go..

Comment: sorry for the damaged code ....still in learning phase ...my point is ...what is to be done here  so that my click event replaces the UI instance by outputpage1 instance in jsp                                          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
          if(e.getSource()==ui.loadTemplate)
          {

                jsp.setViewportView(op1);
                jsp.setVisible(false);
                op1.setVisible(true);
                jsp.getViewport().revalidate();

             // new Demo();
              //jsp.getViewport().repaint();

          }
      }

Comment: You should find better names for your variables. p1 is not communicating its meaning, firstPanel or panelOne would be a lot better. In general you should pay more attention to readability